# Django forms.ChoiceField is always changed

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

`Django==1.10`

I want to use a `models.BooleanField` as a `forms.ChoiceField` in the `admin` app.

## models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    bool_field = models.BooleanField()
```

## admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import MyModel
from .forms import MyModelForm

@admin.register(MyModel)
class TemplateAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyModelForm
    list_display = ['name','bool_field']
```

## forms.py

```
from django import forms

class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    bool_choices = ((True, "Yes"),(False, "No"))
    bool_field = forms.ChoiceField(choices=bool_choices)
```

Everything displays just like I want, but in fact every time I save the instance the `History` link shows that the `bool_field` was changed even if it wasn't.

I tried to change the `bool_field` to `TypedChoiceField` with `coerce=bool`, but it doesn't work well. After I change and save the instance the value remains the same.

Please advise what I should probably change in order to get `History` working right.

Comment: Where’s the rest of your form’s code? If it’s a ModelForm it needs a `model` and `fields` attribute

Comment: @dirkgroten doesn't `django` get it from `admin.py`? This is all I have.

Comment: sorry, didn't realise this is an admin view. you're right.

Answer (score 1):

Try and specify that the `bool_field` is not required, like so:

```
bool_field = forms.ChoiceField(choices=bool_choices, required=False)
```

Comment: The problem remains. Every time I save the instance `History` says that the field was changed.

Comment: Did you try using a `TypedChoiceField` and `coerce=bool` with `required=False`?

Comment: Yes, I tried both. With that I cannot change `bool_field`'s value. After I choose "No" and click "Save" the value of the field doesn't change, it's still "Yes".